# How to find File ID of Uploaded Doc using Google API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Below is the code I am using to upload a file using Java.

File is getting uploaded, but I want to know the File ID of uploaded file?

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");

DocsService docService = new DocsService("Doc");
docService.setUserCredentials("email@gmail.com","password");

DocumentListEntry uploadFile = new DocumentListEntry();
uploadFile.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("FileName"));
uploadFile.setFile(new File("/path/test.csv"), "text/plain");
uploadFile = docService.insert(feedUrl, uploadFile);
```

How to find the File ID of uploaded file?

I wanted to upload a doc & share it using Google API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/docs/DocumentListEntry), it's in

```
uploadFile.getDocId()
```